# read in a column of integers from a text file c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to use get line to read a "zip code column of integers from a `.txt` file in this format:

`Name|Address|Zipcode|DateOfBirth`

This is relevant part of what I have so far:

```
std::ifstream testfile;
testfile.open("data.txt");
string zipcode;
std::vector<int> inputVec;
while(!testfile.eof())
{
  std::getline(testfile, zipcode, '|' );
  // Need to store all zipcodes as ints in an array or vector
  // inputVec.push_back(zipcode);
  // trying to cout to screen to make sure its the right col.

   cout<<zipcode<<endl;  // not working 
}
```

However, this is reading the entire file when I just want the zip code column.

How do I only "grab" that column between `'|'` symbols?

Comment: Read all columns, ignore those you don't need. Unless your columns are of fixed width (allowing you to skip forward `n` bytes), there is no more effective way. And, honestly, it won't matter anyway.

Comment: Please don't assume that zip-codes are always integers.  In the UK they are things like "CB4 3PT".  Given that you can't do arithmetic with zip-codes, just treat them as strings.

Comment: A zip code should not be an integer, It should be a string.  zip codes can start with a `0` and integers cannot.

Comment: @NathanOliver : Wonderful.  A *local* reason why they need to be strings.

Comment: Also: `while (!foo.eof())` is almost always a bug (and this is not an exception).

Comment: Edit: none of the zipcodes in my file start with `0` or contain characters, they are 5 digit US zipcodes

Comment: @DevSolar do you mean having an array for each column?

Comment: No, I mean `Name` into `mystring`, then reading `Address` into `mystring`, then reading `Zipcode` into `mystring` *and storing it in your vector*. Read until end of line, repeat. Note the comment by Jerry Coffin.

Comment: @M.Malik Why not future proof it and still make it a string?  That way you do not need to change anything to accept zip codes starting with a 0 or zip codes from other countries.

Comment: if you already know that the data format for each readed line is: **Name|Address|Zipcode|DateOfBirth** then you can read the string until you find for the second time the character **"|"** and read until you found it again... More info: [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/), Hope it helps.

Comment: @NathanOliver why i don't want to use a string is b/c i am going to be sorting them numerically. will that work if I use string instead?

Comment: @M.Malik Since all of the string are the same size then yes you can sort the strings just like you would integers.  The only time string sorting breaks down with numbers is when you have strings of different lengths.  It can be fixed but you have to write a custom compare function that compares the length first.

Comment: @M.Malik [Beginners guide to the std::sort() function](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz/) some documentation about sorting vectors... short answer, Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> How I only "grab" that column between '|' symbols?

Text record in file:

```
Name|Address|Zipcode|DateOfBirth
    1       2       3
```

A possible approach (but grab the whole line, not just the column)

```
int t394(void)
{
   std::ifstream testfile;
   testfile.open("data.txt");

   std::string aTxtRecord;

   std::vector<std::string> inputVec;  // tbd - or integer

   do // read in whole file
   {
      // read entire line, one record at a time
      std::getline(testfile, aTxtRecord);

      if(testfile.eof())  break;  // completed

      // in the line, find one interesting '|', 
      //    perhaps the first after zip, last in the line
      size_t mrkr3 = aTxtRecord.rfind('|'); // last |
      if(mrkr3 == std::string::npos) // not found
      {
         //handle bad record - no marker in the string
         // set error code?  std::cerr << from here?
         break;  // file invalid, maybe should quite
      }
      // mrkr3 now points at the marker behind the Zipcode

      // find mrkr2 in front of the Zipcode
      // use find 2 times?  
      // use rfind 1 more time?  
      size_t mrkr2 = 0; // tbd

      // validate record - total mrkrs in line?

      // compute length of zip string i.e. mrkr3 - mrkr2 - 1?
      size_t length = mrkr3 - mrkr2;  // ? -1 or -2

      // now extract the Zipcode substring
      // compute how many chars in zipcode field 
      std::string zipcode = aTxtRecord.substr(mrkr2+1, // char after mrkr2
                                              length);  

      // store all zipcodes as strings (or tbd ints) in an array or vector
      inputVec.push_back(zipcode);

      // cout to screen for manual verification
      std::cout << zipcode << std::endl;

   } while(1);  // only exit is error or eof()

   testfile.close(); // possibly not needed

   // sort the vector

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Decide to undelete this.  I hope this is not 'too much' help.  I got more.